# Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

Please assist,

I have upgraded my flutter to 3.0.1 • channel stable ,

dart sdk version to Dart SDK version: 2.17.1 (stable) (Tue May 17 17:58:21 2022 +0000) on "windows_x64".

kotlin version ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20' in /android/build.gradle file.

When I try to start my app I get the following error

```
C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\photo_manager-
1.3.10\android\src\main\kotlin\top\kikt\imagescanner\core\PhotoManagerPlugin.kt: (128, 36): Type 
mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected
e: C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\photo_manager-
1.3.10\android\src\main\kotlin\top\kikt\imagescanner\core\PhotoManagerPlugin.kt: (128, 41): Type 
mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction   
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'm not sure what else is missing. I did not edit any kotlin code.

Kotlin MainActivity.kt

```
package com.company.app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

PhotoManagerPlugin.kt code

```
package top.kikt.imagescanner.core

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.entity.AssetEntity
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.entity.FilterOption
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.entity.PermissionResult
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.entity.ThumbLoadOption
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.utils.ConvertUtils
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.utils.IDBUtils
import top.kikt.imagescanner.core.utils.belowSdk
import top.kikt.imagescanner.permission.PermissionsListener
import top.kikt.imagescanner.permission.PermissionsUtils
import top.kikt.imagescanner.util.LogUtils
import top.kikt.imagescanner.util.ResultHandler
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

/// create 2019-09-05 by cai


class PhotoManagerPlugin(
    private val applicationContext: Context,
    messenger: BinaryMessenger,
    private var activity: Activity?,
    private val permissionsUtils: PermissionsUtils
) : MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {

    val deleteManager = PhotoManagerDeleteManager(applicationContext, activity)

    fun bindActivity(activity: Activity?) {
        this.activity = activity
        deleteManager.bindActivity(activity)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val poolSize = 8
        private val threadPool: ThreadPoolExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor(
            poolSize + 3,
            1000,
            200,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            ArrayBlockingQueue(poolSize + 3)
        )

        fun runOnBackground(runnable: () -> Unit) {
            threadPool.execute(runnable)
        }

        var cacheOriginBytes = true
    }

    private val notifyChannel = PhotoManagerNotifyChannel(applicationContext, messenger, Handler())

    init {
        permissionsUtils.permissionsListener = object : PermissionsListener {
            override fun onDenied(
                deniedPermissions: MutableList<String>,
                grantedPermissions: MutableList<String>
            ) {
            }

            override fun onGranted() {
            }
        }
    }

    private val photoManager = PhotoManager(applicationContext)

    private var ignorePermissionCheck = false

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val resultHandler = ResultHandler(result, call)

        if (call.method == "ignorePermissionCheck") {
            val ignore = call.argument<Boolean>("ignore")!!
            ignorePermissionCheck = ignore
            resultHandler.reply(ignore)
            return
        }

        var needLocationPermissions = false

        val handleResult = when (call.method) {
            "releaseMemCache" -> {
                photoManager.clearCache()
                resultHandler.reply(1)
                true
            }
            "log" -> {
                LogUtils.isLog = call.arguments()
                resultHandler.reply(1)
                true
            }
            "openSetting" -> {
                permissionsUtils.getAppDetailSettingIntent(activity)
                resultHandler.reply(1)
                true
            }
            "clearFileCache" -> {
                Glide.get(applicationContext).clearMemory()
                runOnBackground {
                    photoManager.clearFileCache()
                    resultHandler.reply(1)
                }
                true
            }
            "forceOldApi" -> {
                photoManager.useOldApi = true
                resultHandler.reply(1)
                true
            }
            "systemVersion" -> {
                resultHandler.reply(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.toString())
                true
            }
            "cacheOriginBytes" -> {
                cacheOriginBytes = call.arguments()
                resultHandler.reply(cacheOriginBytes)
                true
            }
            "getLatLngAndroidQ" -> {
                /// 这里不拦截, 然后额外添加gps权限
                needLocationPermissions = true
                false
            }
            "copyAsset" -> {
                needLocationPermissions = true
                false
            }
            "getFullFile" -> {
                val isOrigin = call.argument<Boolean>("isOrigin")!!
                if (isOrigin && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    needLocationPermissions = true
                }
                false
            }
            "getOriginBytes" -> {
                needLocationPermissions = true
                false
            }
            "getMediaUrl" -> {
                false
            }
            else -> false
        }

        if (handleResult) {
            return
        }

        if (ignorePermissionCheck) {
            onHandlePermissionResult(call, resultHandler, true)
            return
        }

        if (permissionsUtils.isRequesting) {
            resultHandler.replyError(
                "PERMISSION_REQUESTING",
                "Another permission request is still ongoing. Please request after the existing one is done.",
                null
            )
            return
        }

        val utils = permissionsUtils.apply {
            withActivity(activity)
            permissionsListener = object : PermissionsListener {
                override fun onDenied(
                    deniedPermissions: MutableList<String>,
                    grantedPermissions: MutableList<String>
                ) {
                    LogUtils.info("onDenied call.method = ${call.method}")
                    if (call.method == "requestPermissionExtend") {
                        resultHandler.reply(PermissionResult.Denied.value)
                        return
                    }
                    if (grantedPermissions.containsAll(
                            arrayListOf(
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            )
                        )
                    ) {
                        LogUtils.info("onGranted call.method = ${call.method}")
                        onHandlePermissionResult(call, resultHandler, false)
                    } else {
                        replyPermissionError(resultHandler)
                    }
                }

                override fun onGranted() {
                    LogUtils.info("onGranted call.method = ${call.method}")
                    onHandlePermissionResult(call, resultHandler, true)
                }
            }
        }

        val permissions = arrayListOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )

        if (needLocationPermissions && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && haveManifestMediaLocation(
                applicationContext
            )
        ) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
        }

        utils.getPermissions(3001, permissions)
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun haveManifestMediaLocation(context: Context): Boolean {
//        Debug.waitForDebugger()
        val applicationInfo = context.applicationInfo
        val packageInfo = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(
            applicationInfo.packageName,
            PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
        )
        return packageInfo.requestedPermissions.contains(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
    }


    private fun replyPermissionError(resultHandler: ResultHandler) {
        resultHandler.replyError("Request for permission failed.", "User denied permission.", null)
    }

    private fun onHandlePermissionResult(
        call: MethodCall,
        resultHandler: ResultHandler,
        haveLocationPermission: Boolean
    ) {
        when (call.method) {
            "requestPermissionExtend" -> resultHandler.reply(PermissionResult.Authorized.value)
            "getGalleryList" -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                    notifyChannel.setAndroidQExperimental(true)
                }
                runOnBackground {
                    val type = call.argument<Int>("type")!!
                    val hasAll = call.argument<Boolean>("hasAll")!!
                    val option = call.getOption()
                    val onlyAll = call.argument<Boolean>("onlyAll")!!

                    val list = photoManager.getGalleryList(type, hasAll, onlyAll, option)
                    resultHandler.reply(ConvertUtils.convertToGalleryResult(list))
                }
            }
            "getAssetWithGalleryId" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val page = call.argument<Int>("page")!!
                    val pageCount = call.argument<Int>("pageCount")!!
                    val type = call.argument<Int>("type")!!
                    val option = call.getOption()
                    val list = photoManager.getAssetList(id, page, pageCount, type, option)
                    resultHandler.reply(ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(list))
                }
            }
            "getAssetListWithRange" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val galleryId = call.getString("galleryId")
                    val type = call.getInt("type")
                    val start = call.getInt("start")
                    val end = call.getInt("end")
                    val option = call.getOption()
                    val list: List<AssetEntity> =
                        photoManager.getAssetListWithRange(galleryId, type, start, end, option)
                    resultHandler.reply(ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(list))
                }
            }
            "getThumb" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val optionMap = call.argument<Map<*, *>>("option")!!
                    val option = ThumbLoadOption.fromMap(optionMap)
                    photoManager.getThumb(id, option, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "requestCacheAssetsThumb" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val ids = call.argument<List<String>>("ids")!!
                    val optionMap = call.argument<Map<*, *>>("option")!!
                    val option = ThumbLoadOption.fromMap(optionMap)
                    photoManager.requestCache(ids, option, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "cancelCacheRequests" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    photoManager.cancelCacheRequests()
                }
            }
            "assetExists" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    photoManager.assetExists(id, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "getFullFile" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val isOrigin =
                        if (!haveLocationPermission) false else call.argument<Boolean>("isOrigin")!!
                    photoManager.getFile(id, isOrigin, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "getOriginBytes" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    photoManager.getOriginBytes(
                        id,
                        cacheOriginBytes,
                        haveLocationPermission,
                        resultHandler
                    )
                }
            }
            "getMediaUrl" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val type = call.argument<Int>("type")!!
                    val mediaUri = photoManager.getMediaUri(id, type)
                    resultHandler.reply(mediaUri)
                }
            }
            "getPropertiesFromAssetEntity" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val asset = photoManager.getAssetProperties(id)
                    val assetResult = if (asset != null) {
                        ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(asset)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                    resultHandler.reply(assetResult)
                }
            }
            "fetchPathProperties" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    val type = call.argument<Int>("type")!!
                    val option = call.getOption()
                    val pathEntity = photoManager.getPathEntity(id, type, option)
                    if (pathEntity != null) {
                        val mapResult = ConvertUtils.convertToGalleryResult(listOf(pathEntity))
                        resultHandler.reply(mapResult)
                    } else {
                        resultHandler.reply(null)
                    }
                }
            }
            "getLatLngAndroidQ" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")!!
                    // 读取id
                    val location = photoManager.getLocation(id)
                    resultHandler.reply(location)
                }
            }
            "notify" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val notify = call.argument<Boolean>("notify")
                    if (notify == true) {
                        notifyChannel.startNotify()
                    } else {
                        notifyChannel.stopNotify()
                    }
                }
            }
            "deleteWithIds" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    try {
                        val ids = call.argument<List<String>>("ids")!!
                        if (belowSdk(29)) {
                            deleteManager.deleteInApi28(ids)
                            resultHandler.reply(ids)
                        } else if (IDBUtils.isAndroidR) {
                            val uris = ids.map {
                                photoManager.getUri(it)
                            }.toList()
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                deleteManager.deleteInApi30(uris, resultHandler)
                            }
                        } else {
                            val uris = ids.mapNotNull { photoManager.getUri(it) }
                            //            for (id in ids) {
                            //              val uri = photoManager.getUri(id)
                            //              if (uri != null) {
                            //                deleteManager.deleteWithUriInApi29(uri, false)
                            //              }
                            //            }
                            deleteManager.deleteWithUriInApi29(ids, uris, resultHandler, false)
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        LogUtils.error("deleteWithIds failed", e)
                        resultHandler.replyError("deleteWithIds failed")
                    }
                }
            }
            "saveImage" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    try {
                        val image = call.argument<ByteArray>("image")!!
                        val title = call.argument<String>("title") ?: ""
                        val desc = call.argument<String>("desc") ?: ""
                        val relativePath = call.argument<String>("relativePath") ?: ""
                        val entity = photoManager.saveImage(image, title, desc, relativePath)
                        if (entity == null) {
                            resultHandler.reply(null)
                            return@runOnBackground
                        }
                        val map = ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(entity)
                        resultHandler.reply(map)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        LogUtils.error("save image error", e)
                        resultHandler.reply(null)
                    }
                }
            }
            "saveImageWithPath" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    try {
                        val imagePath = call.argument<String>("path")!!
                        val title = call.argument<String>("title") ?: ""
                        val desc = call.argument<String>("desc") ?: ""
                        val relativePath = call.argument<String>("relativePath") ?: ""
                        val entity = photoManager.saveImage(imagePath, title, desc, relativePath)
                        if (entity == null) {
                            resultHandler.reply(null)
                            return@runOnBackground
                        }
                        val map = ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(entity)
                        resultHandler.reply(map)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        LogUtils.error("save image error", e)
                        resultHandler.reply(null)
                    }
                }
            }
            "saveVideo" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    try {
                        val videoPath = call.argument<String>("path")!!
                        val title = call.argument<String>("title")!!
                        val desc = call.argument<String>("desc") ?: ""
                        val relativePath = call.argument<String>("relativePath") ?: ""
                        val entity = photoManager.saveVideo(videoPath, title, desc, relativePath)
                        if (entity == null) {
                            resultHandler.reply(null)
                            return@runOnBackground
                        }
                        val map = ConvertUtils.convertToAssetResult(entity)
                        resultHandler.reply(map)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        LogUtils.error("save video error", e)
                        resultHandler.reply(null)
                    }
                }
            }
            "copyAsset" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val assetId = call.argument<String>("assetId")!!
                    val galleryId = call.argument<String>("galleryId")!!
                    photoManager.copyToGallery(assetId, galleryId, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "moveAssetToPath" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    val assetId = call.argument<String>("assetId")!!
                    val albumId = call.argument<String>("albumId")!!
                    photoManager.moveToGallery(assetId, albumId, resultHandler)
                }
            }
            "removeNoExistsAssets" -> {
                runOnBackground {
                    photoManager.removeAllExistsAssets(resultHandler)
                }
            }
            else -> resultHandler.notImplemented()
        }
    }

    private fun MethodCall.getString(key: String): String {
        return this.argument<String>(key)!!
    }

    private fun MethodCall.getInt(key: String): Int {
        return this.argument<Int>(key)!!
    }

    private fun MethodCall.getOption(): FilterOption {
        val arguments = argument<Map<*, *>>("option")!!
        return ConvertUtils.convertFilterOptionsFromMap(arguments)
    }
}
```

Comment: The log shows there is an error in `C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\photo_manager-
1.3.10\android\src\main\kotlin\top\kikt\imagescanner\core\PhotoManagerPlugin.kt`, so show us that file. Especially the code around line 128 is interesting. You have a `Boolean?` in a place where `Boolean` is expected,  that difference should be clear if you program in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have pasted the PhotoManagerPlugin.kt code, I have no experience in kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem.
Just check your dependencies versions and update the necessary ones.

In my case, my flutter SDK version was 3.3.6 ,  and I discovered that two of my dependencies versions were NOT compatible with the flutter version.

The dependencies were :
1- wechat_assets_picker 6.3.0

2-wechat_camera_picker 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the use of `multi_crop_picker: ^0.0.5`, commented it out and app compiled successfully.